# Most elegant way to dismiss number keyboard for a UITextField on a UiTableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITextField on a UITableView and I am using a number keyboard however I want it to be dismissed when user clicks on anything but the UiTextField.

I have seen several solutions however there appears to not be one definitive answer. For example some talk about gestures and when I implement them they do not appear to work using the code below:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [[self view] endEditing:TRUE];

}
```

As you can see I am trying but there is not one way that seems to be working. Can someone guide me please?

Thanks

Comment: The trick is to send `resignFirstResponder` to whichever control is currently first responder (i.e. your UITextField).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you will want to hit-test the touch against areas which should not dismiss the keyboard; but in general the requirement is to tell the currently-in-focus control to "resign" it's status as "firstResponder". It might look like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 [self.userInput resignFirstResponder];
}
```

However, you may also want to consider a special gesture recognizer for this, so that you are not having to over-analyze the NSSet of touches in the long run (delegate to the GestureRecognizer the task of determining the difference between an actual "dismiss pleas!" tap and a "can I scroll this?" swipe.

Answer (score 3):

You should use resignFirstResponder instead :

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  // Note the '!':
  if(![[touch view] class] isKindOfClass [UITableViewController class]]){
    // It's not a bubble they touched, dismiss the keyboard:
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
  }
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

or else

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  // Note the '!':
  if(![[touch view] class] isKindOfClass [UITableViewController class]]){
    // It's not a bubble they touched, dismiss the keyboard:
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

  }
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

this helps in doing what you want